# why object in javascript does not have find method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I started `node` repl and typed this in

```
> function isPrime(element, index, array) {
...   var start = 2;
...   while (start <= Math.sqrt(element)) {
.....     if (element % start++ < 1) {
.......       return false;
.......     }
.....   }
...   return element > 1;
... }
undefined
> [4, 6, 8, 12].find(isPrime)
TypeError: Object 4,6,8,12 has no method 'find'
    at repl:1:16
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
```

What is wrong here? Why would an array object does not have the `find` method? Isn't it the same as [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)?

Comment: Run Node with ES6 ("Harmony") features enabled.

Comment: is it just `node --harmony`? but it still does not work.

Comment: Well I thought so but now somebody says I'm wrong :( It may not be supported yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`V8` did not realize `.find()` array method for now (see [source](http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/src/array.js)). So `node.js` and `io.js` do not support it. See [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Array.prototype_methods)

Comment: It does if you invoke it with `--harmony`

Comment: @Pointy no, try it youself. I think `v8` does not support find() for now, but can be wrong at this point.

Comment: Oh. Weird. It supports lots of other ES6 stuff; `.find()` certainly doesn't seem exotic.